# what is the probability of committing Type 2 error ,P(accept the null/ the null is false)?

Tags: probability

Error of Type 1:"reject" the null hypothesis when it is true.
Error of type 2:"accept" the null the hypothesis when it is false.

We want to minimize the probability of committing both types of errors.

Question: what is the probability of committing Type 2 error ,P(accept the null/ the null is false)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out how to trade them off - in general, you can't minimize both of them simultaneously. This is why we use curves like the [ROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) (receiver operating characteristic).

Trivially, you can make one error zero with probability $1$ by always declaring one hypothesis or the other.

Neyman-Pearson tests are one way to control the tradeoff (they are most powerful tests). Minimax bayes risk or choosing appropriate priors and Bayes risk are other ways.